# Read document in Firestore from firebase onCall cloud function

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-functions

I am using an `onCall` firebase cloud function to check if a document exists in a collection on the firestore.
If the document exists, i want to continue, if it still does not exist, than i want to create it.

I have tried many different things, but always got errors, so now i am trying to go step-by-step and simply get the content of a file i know exists on the collection. The collection is called "timeline_state" and the document is called "888"

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.afterLogin = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  console.log("afterLogin STARTING");

  const getDocument = admin.firestore().collection('timeline_state').doc('888').get();

  return getDocument.then(doc => {
    console.log(doc);
    return doc
  }).catch(error => {
    console.log(error)
    return error;
 })
})
```

When i call it from my code i get an empty `data` object,
and in the Firebase functions log i see the function runs but i get an error:

```
/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/gaxios/build/src/index.js:28
async function request(opts) {
      ^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token function
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:549:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:445:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:504:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/gcp-metadata/build/src/index.js:17:18)
```

Any ideas on what i am doing wrong, and maybe how i can fix it?
Thanks!

Comment: I am receiving the same error: `/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/gaxios/build/src/index.js:28
async function request(opts) {
      ^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token function
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)

Comment: @Ben the problem is it is running on node 6. Look at my answer to see how to update to node 8. It solved the problem for me!

Comment: Thank you, your answer solved the problem for me as well!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My solution, thanks to a tip i got, was to update the node engine to 8.

To do so, i added the following to the package.json

```
"engines": {
  "node": "8"
}
```

Maybe this is helpful to someone else...   ;)

Comment: Worked for me too.

Comment: This was driving me crazy for the past hour, thank you for restoring my sanity.

Comment: For those who use with node 6, it can be applied in package.json

    "engines": {
     "node": "6"
    }